# Try and Catch with NSUrl(fileURLWithPath)

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch, nsurl

I've been trying to implement try and catch in the following code

```
if let s = songId {     
  let track: NSURL!
  track = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(s, ofType: "mp3")!)
  .............
}
```

I came up with the following code:

```
do {
  track = try NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(s, ofType: "mp3")!)
}
catch let error as NSError {
  print("NSURL Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

But I get the following warnings:

> No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression

and

> 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

And this is strange to me, because this construction usually works.
Only with `NSURL` this construction isn't working.  And I can't figure out why this is happening. Maybe it has something to do with it being an optional, but im not sure.
I can't figure out how to solve this. I need to use a try/catch or something similar, but I can't figure it out how to make it work.

I saw some similar problems on Google, but it didnt gave me an answer.
So my question is: How can I implement a try/catch construction or something similar with NSURL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no methods used that marked with `throws` keyword at the definition. So it really does not make much sense to wrap your code with `try-catch`. I would recommend to consider this:

```
let s = "song"
guard let trackURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(s, withExtension: "mp3") else {
  print("File not found in the app bundle: \(s).mp3")
  return false
}
```

Does it help?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a nice solution!

Comment: Why not even `guard let trackURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(s, withExtension: "mp3") else {...?

Comment: @vadian reasonable observation. Will update as soon as get my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

That initializer doesn't fail and doesn't throw or fail so a try/catch block is unnecessary. The declaration is:

```
public init(fileURLWithPath path: String)
```

If it could throw an error is would be declared as:

```
public init(fileURLWithPath path: String) throws
```

Or if it might fail without throwing an error it would be declared as:

```
public init?(fileURLWithPath path: String)
```

If you're certain that the bundle will always contain the track you're looking for then you can just use

```
let track = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(s, ofType: "mp3")!)
```

Comment: Its possible that the variable contains a track name that doesnt exist. So I have to check for that. Thanks for the answer though. The declaration part is helpful!